# How to create a random 16 digits number, with specific first digits?

Tags: java

I want to create a randomly generated 16 digit-number in java.But there is a catch I need the first two digits to be "52". For example, **52**89-7894-2435-1967.
 I was thinking of using a random generator and create a 14 digit number and then add an integer 5200 0000 0000 0000.
 I tried looking for similar problems and  can't really find something useful. I'm not familiar with the math method,maybe it could solve the problem for me.

Comment: Generate (pseudo)random number. Prefix it with '52'?

Comment: One google search. The rest should be easy with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709521/how-do-i-generate-a-random-n-digit-integer-in-java-using-the-biginteger-class

Comment: Yes,I've made that thought as well, but I don't know how to do it. This was my problem to begin with.

Comment: You should probably look at these two :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655931/12-digit-unique-random-number-generation-in-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328822/generating-10-digits-unique-random-number-in-java

Comment: Your idea, to randomly create a 14-digit number and then add 5200000000000000 to it (or convert it to a string and prepend `"52"`) makes sense.  Do you care about whether every possible 14-digit number could be generated, or is it acceptable if your random number generator misses some possibilities?  Do you care about how uniform the distribution is?

Comment: Or Google "generate random mastercard number"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to generate a random 14-digit number, like you've done:

```
long first14 = (long) (Math.random() * 100000000000000L);
```

Then you add the `52` at the beginning.

```
long number = 5200000000000000L + first14;
```

One other way that would work equally well, and will save memory, since `Math.random()` creates an internal `Random` object:

```
//Declare this before you need to use it
java.util.Random rng = new java.util.Random(); //Provide a seed if you want the same ones every time
...
//Then, when you need a number:
long first14 = (rng.nextLong() % 100000000000000L) + 5200000000000000L;
//Or, to mimic the Math.random() option
long first14 = (rng.nextDouble() * 100000000000000L) + 5200000000000000L;
```

Note that `nextLong() % n` will not provide a perfectly random distribution, unlike `Math.random()`. However, if you're just generating test data and it doesn't have to be cryptographically secure, it works as well. It's up to you which one to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate 14 random digits and then append at the beginning "52". E.g.

```
public class Tes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generateRandom(52));
    }

    public static long generateRandom(int prefix) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        long x = (long)(rand.nextDouble()*100000000000000L);

        String s = String.valueOf(prefix) + String.format("%014d", x);
        return Long.valueOf(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also add the `52` by adding `5200000000000000` (plus or minus a few zeros) to the `x`, if you don't want to use `String` processes to add numbers. It feels cleaner to me.

Comment: Actually, the code you've posted, that uses the `String` to add a prefix, is wrong.  It will fail if `x` is less than 10^13.  You'd need something like `String.format("%014d", x)`.

Comment: Are the digits of `(long)(rand.nextDouble()*100000000000000L)` uniformly distributed? Would probably be better to use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2546186/1178016

Answer (score 3):

```
Random rand = new Random();
String yourValue = String.format((Locale)null, //don't want any thousand separators
                        "52%02d-%04d-%04d-%04d",
                        rand.nextInt(100),
                        rand.nextInt(10000),
                        rand.nextInt(10000),
                        rand.nextInt(10000));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a 14 random digit number. with `Math.random`
- Concatenate to it at the begining the "52" `String`.
- Convert the string with `Integer.parseInt(String)` method

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't explained how to do the first step.  This is not trivial, since `Random.nextLong()` doesn't allow you specify a bound, unlike `Random.nextInt(bound)`.